# Automatic grouping in PivotTable

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sales dataset with ~300k entries, imported from a csv in powerquery.
The data contains a column where each products ID is given and the ID is assigned so that products are categorized. IDs all look something like:

```
123.45.67 - product 1
123.45.68 - product 2
123.99.1 - product 3 
123.101.1 - product 4
123.101.2 - product 5
120.1.3 - product 6
...
```

I've created a pivot report to analyze the data but I would like to group it automatically so that, for example, everything under 123.45 is grouped, 123.101 is a different group etc etc.
I know this can be done manually but I couldn't find a way to automate this process.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can certainly set up your groups and do the grouping in Power Query.  Depending on what you want for a report, you may be able to do the whole process in Power Query.  Or load the table from PQ to a Pivot Table Report.

Answer (score 0):

An example of what of your expected results might help.

A thought is adding an additional column to crop out the extra digits like this might help.

[image]

Then you can create your pivot.